# Randomize search result in sphinx

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

Hi im using sphinx 201 beta (r2792)

i have rt index with rt_attr_uint = rake my goal is to sort results by this attribute
whitch work as expected using

```
$this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'rake DESC')
```

but i want to also randomize this result ... lets say i have this data

```
(id,  title,  rake)
  1, 'test',  3
  2, 'test2', 3
  3, 'ásdf',  1
  4, 'rreer', 0
```

so after i append random

```
$this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'rake DESC, @random')
```

i would expect randomize result sorted by attribute rake descending
but im getting error:

```
sort-by attribute '@random' not found
```

whitch i dont understand because this random attribute is internal attribute
am i doing something wrong? where could be a problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is create the random number on the SQL query

```
SELECT ...  RAND() as random_sort, ...
```

Added it as an attribute

```
sql_attr_float = random_sort
```

And then use it in the extended sort query

```
$this->sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, 'rake DESC, random_sort DESC');
```

Answer (score 2):

From my quick tests, it looks like Sphinx only supports @random if it is the only attribute in the sort clause. So I'm afraid you're out of luck - either you *just* sort randomly, or you *just* sort by rake.

Comment: Hey Pat! I'm wanting to achieve the same with our `thinking_sphinx`/`flying_sphinx` setup 13 years later. Happen to know if there's a solution for this today that doesn't involve a random value in the index itself? :)  Seems to me that @random is on it's way out and that RAND() has the same limitation you mention above.

Comment: @rogerkk  unfortunately I'm not aware of any other way around this, especially if you've found it's still happening in recent Sphinx/Manticore releases.

Answer (score 0):

For real time randomness, index the ids and sort using expr mode with an expression like this (not sure this one is 100% random):

```
( ( ( id % #{pagesize} + #{rand(pagesize * 2)} ) % #{pagesize} ) / #{pagesize} )
```

Add an If statement to the expression above to use your rake attribute.

[http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sorting-modes.html][1]